# Google Apps Script: pass return value from one function to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two scripts:

Script A: Takes raw data from an input sheet and outputs formatted data (stored in `var resultRows` to the output sheet.

Script B: Stores `resultRows` to a MySQL database.

Here's how I would like the process to work:

1. User runs script A, verifies that the information is correct.
2. If the information is correct, user runs Script B to store the data.

One way to do this would be to re-generate `resultRows` in Script B and then insert to DB, but I know I should be able to pass `resultRows` from Script A to Script B as an argument. Something like..

```
function scriptA() {
    //dosomestuff
    return resultRows;
}

function scriptB(data) {
    //insert data to db
}

scriptB(resultRows);
```

Script A is executed from the Google Spreadsheets menu (via the `.addMenu` method), but I don't know how to pass an argument to a function that's executed in this way (you can only pass a funciton name to `.addMenu`) and I'm not sure the `resultRows` variable would be available to the function in any case.

Maybe running the function from a UI element makes more sense? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will be possible for the same reason that Global Variables are problematic in Apps Script. I think that pushing the second button on the menu will create a new context to be created in your script, basically eliminating all previously set variables. You could put the `resultRows` in scriptDb, but it may be easier just to  reread your resultRows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the cache service?

I was able to pass a value from one function to another by pushing the value to a key via the cache service and recall it in the other function. Am not sure how long cache service can store it.